# solaris studio link against specific libc.so version

Tags: linker, solaris, libc

i want to compile/link on a new solaris version (libc.so SUNW_1.22.6) for a system with an older solaris (libc.so SUNW_1.22.4). How can I specify that the linker (on the new version) should build a binary that uses the older (1.22.4) libc.so?

Answer (score 1):

In general, UNIX systems support backward compatibility (a program built on an older system continues to work on a newer system), but not the opposite: a program built on a newer system may not work on an older system.

For this reason, build your program on the oldest OS release you are going to support.

> How can I specify that the linker (on
>   the new version) should build a binary
>   that uses the older (1.22.4) libc.so

You would need a "new Solaris -> old Solars" cross-compiler for that. GCC can be built for such cross-compilation, but this is not trivial. Building on an older system is usually much simpler approach.

Answer (score 0):

Don't call any functions that aren't in SUNW_1.22.4.   The linker records the minimum dependency based on the functions linked to.